# Does $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}2\right) = 0$?

Tags: trigonometry, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I am studying chapter 10 (Partial Differential Equations and Fourier Series) of Boyce's Elementary Differential Equations and I stumbled upon this question:

*Consider the conduction of heat in a rod $40~\rm cm$ in length whose ends are maintained at $0^\circ\rm C$ for
all $t > 0$. In the below question find an expression for the temperature $u(x, t)$ if the initial temperature distribution in the rod is the given function. Suppose that $α_2 = 1$.*

$u(x, 0) = \begin{cases}
    x & \ 0 \le x \lt20\\
    40-x & \  20 \le x \le40\\
      \end{cases}
    \\$

While I was checking the soluotion of this question I found online I saw in one of the steps involved below is treated as zero:

$$\cos\frac{\frac{(n\pi L)}{2}}{L} = 0.$$

I just wish to ask why is that the case that the above equals zero? For instance if $n = 2$ shouldn't the above equals $\cos(\pi) = -1$?

Thank you!

*this link is a screenshot of the solution I found online:
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5SLR.jpg ;  link to the full solution is here: !https://math.berkeley.edu/~ogus/old/Math_54-05/HW%20solutions/homework509.pdf

Comment: Your links say $\cos \frac{n\pi L/2}{L}$, not what you wrote.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out I think it's changed by Tianlalu while he's correcting a bunch of formatting error I made... let me change it back thanks both of you

Comment: Ah, I see, yes. I don't understand why they would deliberately change the meaning without confirming with you. As to the question, the expression is $0$ for odd $n$.

Comment: $n$ is an odd integer.